# How to import user created package in jupyter notebook of SysML v2?

Tags: jupyter, sysml

I have some sysml2 files, and want to import them in a jupyter notebook.
How to do this?

I have followed the [instructions](https://github.com/Systems-Modeling/SysML-v2-Release/blob/master/install/jupyter/install.sh) to install the jupyter sysml, and can import standard library package in a sysml kernel notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the .sysml file to `miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels\sysml\sysml.library\Domain Library` to import.
And if want to reload the files from change, select `kernel - restart kernel` in the jupter web interface to reload files.

The discussion is in the [github issue](https://github.com/Systems-Modeling/SysML-v2-Pilot-Implementation/issues/430).